# Index with double Match returns incorrect closest values

Tags: excel-formula

I have an planning exported to Excel which looks like the following (tab ' Data'):
[image: Example]

Each production line has a number of people working on it. Now is my goal to show how many people are working on a line per minute. We plan per product group, and several product groups combined form waht a line has to do per minute.

To get the production per minute I created the following (tab 'Conversie'):
[image]

```
=INDEX(Data!$H$2:$H$157;MATCH($N$1&A4;Data!$B$2:$B$157&Data!$C$2:$C$157;1))
```

In the example it works correct. However, the formula doesn't seem to always return the correct "Artikelomschrijving"(H) every time. I get incorrect return values when I extend this formula to other product groups.

I read that the data needs to be sorted ascending cause I use match_type 1. When I do that I get the right returns for some product groups, but the given example suddenly returns incorrect values.

I can't sort both column C and A in ascending order for the formulas to always return correct items. Can you help me to get past this hurdle?

Comment: It would need to sorted on both the name and the time.

Comment: So the only solution is to split the data? Cause I need to sort on one column and can 'sub-sort'  the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, thank you for pointing me in the right direction Valon Miller. This is the formula I fixed it with:

```
 =ALS.FOUT(INDEX(Data!$H$2:$H$154;MATCH(1;(Conversie!L$1=Data!$B$2:$B$154)*((Conversie!$A32>=Data!$C$2:$C$154)*(Conversie!$A32<=Data!$D$2:$D$154));0));"")
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of google translate work, if I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to find the "Item Description" (H) of the record where the "Line" (B) = the value in N1 and the time is between the start and end times.

**This is an array formula, you have to confirm it with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`**

`=INDEX(Data!$H$2:$H$157,MATCH(1,(Data!$B$2:$B$157=$N$1)*(Data!$C$2:$C$157<$A2)*(Data!$D$2:$D$157>=$A2),0))`

OR with semicolon syntax:

`=INDEX(Data!$H$2:$H$157;MATCH(1;(Data!$B$2:$B$157=$N$1)*(Data!$C$2:$C$157<$A2)*(Data!$D$2:$D$157>=$A2);0))`

Comment: I am glad you clarified my request. Unfortunatly when I try the formula I just get errors. This part of the formula Data!$B$2:$B$157=$N$1 results in False. So the Match will look in the search matrix "False"  or "True", which generates the error.